# POST request works with small file but not with large file

Tags: python, api, rest, post, large-files

I am able to make a POST request through a python script to upload a file to server.

Code logic I have developed,

```
import requests
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from fake_useragent import UserAgent    

ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.chrome)

class _TokenAuth(AuthBase):
    """
    Helper class for requests Auth field. AuthBase requires you to implement the __call__
    magic function.
    """
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + self.token
        return r

token = 'ERXYUtuUwVS'
auth = _TokenAuth(token)    

custom_POST_header = {"User-Agent": str(ua.chrome),
                        "Filename": "OurUseCase.csv"
                            } 

with open('OurUseCase.csv', 'rb') as file_to_upload:
    file_dict = {'OurUseCase.csv': file_to_upload}
    response_obj = requests.post(url='https://open.abc.xyz.com/api/files',
                                 data=custom_POST_header,
                                 files= file_dict,
                                 auth=auth)
print(f'Status of POST request: {response_obj.status_code}')
```

**Problem**

This script works fine for small size csv file (57 KB in my case). But when I tries to upload a file of approx. size 650 MB, the same script throws the below error:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Any chance this could be linked to some restrictions from your server, or a timeout?

Comment: It can be a case but not sure, I see a long traceback with ConnectionResetError. Like, request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1239         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1240         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)